# Class 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb for connecting to Mongodb with laravel 5, i have installed MongoDB php driver and then laravel-mongodb with command `composer require jenssegers/mongodb`, then added service provider in app/config/app.php:

```
'Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider',
```

and refreshed my website, unfortunately i got error  ->

```
FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 6466:
Class 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider' not found
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `composer dump-autoload` or `php artisan optimize`

Comment: i have used `composer dump -o ` `composer dump-autoload` and both of this functions worked but no success

Comment: `php artisan optimize` got error  'could not open file artisan'

Comment: you should be in your project root directory, where the file `artisan` is located. Anyway, try to remove the compiled.php file, and refresh the page

Comment: also, do you have the file `vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/MongodbServiceProvider.php` ?

Comment: there is not jenssegers in vendors folder ... it seem i have installed it in another folder how can i install it in desired directory ?

Comment: assuming you are under unix, go to your desired folder, then run: `composer require jenssegers/mongodb` be sure to be in the same directory of the `artisan` file

Comment: getting same error and i m in same directory where artisan file available

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have the archive:
**myproject/vendor/jenssegers.**

I installed this archive by command:

```
$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete Following Files and Use This Step :

> composer.lock
>
> bootstrap/cache/config.php

if exist

> bootstrap/cache/services.php

then Run this command :

> composer install
>
> php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 0):

If the previously mentioned solutions won't do the trick, it is possible that some dependencies are missing. Simply try:

```
$ composer install
```